# How to handle a column with Time Duration in a Dataframe (Pandas, Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose if in one column of a dataframe there is duration. How do I convert that into seconds? . It's given in duration like 00:00:50 that is 50 seconds

[image]

Comment: what is the output of `type(df.loc[0,'Duration'])`?

Comment: datetime.time is the type

Comment: But when i am using df.info() the dtype of duration shows as object.

Comment: `df['Duration'].apply(lambda x:x.second)` is working fine from my side but it's giving you and error for `datetime.time` values

Comment: Ok so i converted the type to string and pd.to_timedelta(df['duration']).dt.total_seconds() worked. Thank you.